# Java: How to extract a Count from ResultSet Select query

Tags: java, sql, count, resultset

This question has been answered before here but the solutions that were posted are not working for me. Following is my code:

```
Statement query = this.conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = query.executeQuery("Select COUNT(*) FROM Questions AS total");
            resultSet.next();
            int totalQuestions = resultSet.getInt("total");
            System.out.println(totalQuestions);
            System.exit(1);
            resultSet.close();
```

It just keeps on saying column total not found. I have tried it without "resultSet.next()" as well but same issue. I have also tried resultSet.getInt(1) but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `ResultSet resultSet = query.executeQuery("Select COUNT(*)  AS total FROM Questions");` and you are done....

Answer (score 1):

The SQL syntax you want is

```
Select COUNT(*) AS total FROM Questions
```

or alternatively, you could just write `Select COUNT(*) FROM Questions`
and use `resultSet.getInt(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Select COUNT(*) FROM Questions AS total
```

to:

```
Select COUNT(*) AS total FROM Questions
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is a little bit wrong. Try:

```
ResultSet resultSet = query.executeQuery("Select COUNT(*) AS total FROM Questions");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this,

The SQL syntax is

```
Select COUNT(*) AS total FROM Questions
```